# How to insert data into to two defferent table form a windowform?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i try to insert data table to two table from a windowform , so i found this code :

```
INSERT INTO patient (id, name, sex), checkIn (chID, Date, illness) VALUES ('" & txt1.text & "', '" & txt2.text & "','" & txt3.text & "','" & txt4.text & "', '" & txt5.text & "', '" & txt6.text & "')
```

is it correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not insert data into 2 tables simultaneously. Split the insert statements into 2 statements

```
INSERT INTO patient(id, name, sex) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)
INSERT INTO checkIn(chID, Date, illness) VALUES (value4, value5, value6)
```

The only way to insert data in two tables using a single SQL statement is using `OUTPUT` clause which returns information from each row affected by an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `MERGE` statement.

```
INSERT INTO [table1] ([data]) 
OUTPUT [inserted].[id], [external_table].[col2] 
INTO [table2] SELECT [col1] 
FROM [external_table]
```

Answer (score 0):

it's return the error like below

```
 Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
 Incorrect syntax near tablename
```

you have to write both statement seperate.

```
insert into tablename1(col1,col2,col3) value (val1,val2,val3)
insert into tablename2(col4,col5,col63 value (val4,val5,val6)
```